# Meaning of いくら and って in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

The speaker just stated that her father is too sure of himself.

> いくらママが死んじゃって　いないからってさ！ (there is a space in the manga as well)
>
> チャンピオンなのを利用していろんな女の人と遊びまくってんのよ！
>
> He uses his title to have fun with every girl that moves!

---

Ok, first, I don't get the meaning of いくら here... is it a casual way of using the いくら...~ても/でも form (I.E. dropping the も)?

It still wouldn't make sense to me : "No matter how much mom died.."?? or is it just to stress the concession : "Ok, EVEN though mom is dead..."?

---

I don't understand who's the subject of いない either, is it the dead mom? Is it a way of saying he hasn't found another wife yet (新妻がいない...)?

---

As at that point I basicaly only understood that her mom is dead, I don't know who's the subject of って and if it's short for 言う or 思う...

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subject of って (と言って) is void or general you/they and that of いない is ママ (I guess it refers to a owner of a bar here). So, the whole いくら「ママが死んじゃっていないから」って translates into "no matter how much you say because the lady is dead and gone", and in more natural sounding English (aside from "lady"), "(he shouldn't do it) even if the lady is dead and gone".